# select all child elements except H1 and H2?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code like this:

```
<section>
  <header>
  <p>intro text</p>
  <h1>some text</h1>
  </header>
  <div><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div><h2>some text</h2></div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <span>some meta text</span>
  <button>push me</button>
</section>
```

Now I want to select every element except the header tags. Is that possible? Tried with "(not)" but it is not working (I think "not" can't handle an array).

Is there an alternative way to handle this? I mean without using "not".

Comment: What language / technology are you trying to use to "select all child elements"?  You say that you've 'tried with "(not)" but it is not working'.  There's no "array" in this code, so your statement doesn't make sense here, without the necessary context that *only you have*.  Please show what you've tried, and how it's not working (errors, pics, etc).  This is not a complete question.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.

Comment: You are right, but I saw in another answer it works this way: *:not(h1):not(h2).